# Access text file and read integers inside to Array ? Help Please

Tags: java, android, arrays, file, text

Having trouble with an app

I need to read the data from a text file it contains one integer on each line and i need to read it into an array and double them then output it to another text file. however, i cant get the file to open and be read so i can add them to the array.

```
package com.example.doubleandsave;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


int[] inArray; 

File infile = new File("inputtextfile.txt");

Scanner fsc = new Scanner(infile);


AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
Scanner fsc1 = new Scanner(assetManager.open("inputtextfile.txt")); 





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

these two lines gives me the error Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit 
 constructor

Anyone know how I would fix this ? #fixed#

this is the gist of what i have to do

1. Open the input (text) file with the given name (first EditText field above). This file should appear in the 
   “assets” directory of your app. It should contain a list of grades (one per line). Read the grades into an 
   array. (If the file does not exist, display an appropriate message in the text area of the screen labeled 
   “Status.” above.)
2. Using a method double all the values in the array. (Include this method in your main 
   activity class and call it from the method responding to the button press.)
3. Output the list of the doubled grades (one per line) to a new file with the given name (second EditText 
   field above). This file should appear in your app’s external files directory, which can be obtained using 
   the built-in SDK “getExternalFilesDir” method. NOTE: Check to see if the output file already exists
   before opening it. If it does, do not overwrite it. Display an appropriate message for the user in the status 
   text area and don’t write anything to the file.

Comment: Is inputtextfile.txt located in the same directory as your java file?

Comment: start by knowing where your file is

Comment: it is in my assets directory

Comment: http://imgur.com/aLLb7zs

Comment: you can see it there. Im not sure why I get this error

Comment: put your txt file in any resource folder.create raw folder inside res and access it through getrawresourse(rough solution).

Comment: @njzk2 my file is located in my apps assets directory

Comment: `assetManager.open("inputtextfile.txt")` is a good start then.

Comment: @njzk2 yeah got that im trying to double the values in array now.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor.

is quite clear. You have a base class of which the constructor throws an `IOException`:

```
public class BaseClass {

    public BaseClass() throws IOException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And you are trying to subclass it:

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {

}
```

But the (now implicit) constructor of `SubClass` implicitly calls `super()` which throws an exception for which the subclass is not prepared at all, since the implicit constructor looks like this:

```
public SubClass() {
    super();  // this throws an IOException which is not declared to be thrown by SubClass constructor
}
```

So, you must define an explicit constructor:

```
public SubClass() throws IOException { 
    super();
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem in fact is caused by initializing instance fields with initializers throwing exceptions. In this case you have to move them in a constructor which throws the exception:

```
public MainActivity() throws IOException {
    File infile = new File("inputtextfile.txt");

    Scanner fsc = new Scanner(infile);


    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    Scanner fsc1 = new Scanner(assetManager.open("inputtextfile.txt"));
}
```

Comment: how would i fix this ? So using Assetmanager caused this error ?

Comment: @JeffKimson could you show more of your code? A minimal, compilable class which still shows the errors...

Comment: @ Katona do you want me to post everything on the post at the top ?

Comment: @JeffKimson Please stop posting images and edit your question to include the code.

Comment: @Katona Thanks so much it stopped giving me that error. This site is quick and resourceful. Thanks again if I have anymore problems I will post again

Comment: Anyone know how i would input text data into array ? it is 1 integer per line.

Comment: @ Katona do you know how i would make a system to check to see if the file is there. it says it will read values from array but im not sure as to make it report back if file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try relative path first for debug. some thing like :File file = new File("./target/test.txt");

Comment: got it. do you know how i would then double those array values ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute code outside of a method. Change your code to this, where I have split the declaration and initialisation:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int[] inArray; 

    File infile;

    Scanner fsc;

    AssetManager assetManager;
    Scanner fsc1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        infile = new File("inputtextfile.txt");

        fsc = new Scanner(infile);

        assetManager = getAssets();

        fsc1 = new Scanner(assetManager.open("inputtextfile.txt")); 

    }
```

Note.  You should take time to learn about the activity life cycle.  Doing this in `onCreate()` is possibly not the best place.  You might also find a collection easier to work with than `int[]`, possibly `ArrayList<Integer>`